# Trying to select a value from a drop-down

Tags: javascript, c#, dom, cefsharp

One Form on the page I am accessing. This form has a dropdown with 3 options. I need to select the third option. Accessing the webpage from a C# program with cefsharp library (embedded web browser).

I can change the displayed text using

```
document.forms[0].getElementsByClassName('css-0 Select__single-value')[0].innerText="Keep in-play";
```

but this has not been registered. Have also tried to trigger input and change events but it is still not recognising my selection. 
Any suggestions?

Here is the original DOM for the form:

```html
<div class="bet-widget-optional-params">
  <div class="bet-params">
    <div class="param-wrapper"><span class="param-label"><a class="link" href="https://help.smarkets.com/hc/en-gb/articles/115003946591" target="_blank">Time In Force</a></span>
      <div class="param-select">
        <div class="css-0 Select custom-select-box Select menu-on-click">
          <div class="css-0 Select__control">
            <div class="css-0 Select__value-container Select__value-container--has-value">
              <div class="css-0 Select__single-value">Default</div><input id="react-select-bet-param-selector-input" readonly="" tabindex="0" class="css-14uuagi" value=""></div>
            <div class="css-0 Select__indicators"><span class="css-0 Select__indicator-separator"></span><span aria-hidden="true" class="Select__arrow-zone"><span class="Select__arrow"></span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Ian, can you provide more info on your DOM structure, because the code I suggested should work just fine.

Comment: Stephen - thanks for the interest. As a new user I can't see any way to copy screen shots into a reply - or am I missing something. Am using Inspect Element in Firefox and it doesn't seem to allow me to highlight the relevant DOM lines and copy them.

Comment: Yeah it won’t let new users post images, the source code copy of the DOM would be better. You can copy it from the view source CTRL+U

Comment: Stephen - this is where my lack of knowledge becomes apparent. The form is only displayed when I click on the initial displayed page. If I do CTRL-U, the source for the displayed form can't be found (at least not by me). Maybe you could have a look at the page directly. Go to https://smarkets.com/event/18340174/sport/horse-racing/wolverhampton/2019/10/03/201910032015. You will see a list of horse names and 4 boxes to the right of each. Click on any of the Blue boxes - they will either have a decimal number or Ask inside. The drop down is in the displayed form title Time In Force

Comment: What I think is happening here is that new HTML is being added by Javascript. Certainly when you select the arrow to the right of the dropdown, a new class appears in the DOM - unfortunately I can't expand the class to see what elements are inside it.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to view the site my corp network blocks gambling related sites by default. If you follow your steps, then right click and choose "Inspect Element" in Firefox, you should see the DOM with your element highlighted. Navigate the DOM tree as you need until the containing element is highlighted and then right click and choose "Edit as HTML" - from there you should be able to highlight, copy and past the generated code. (press Escape to break out of this mode)

Comment: One step forward - two steps backward - Edit as HTML was successful but 239 characters too long to paste as a comment!!!

Comment: ah, yes, you can edit your original post as much as you need.

Comment: DOM added eventually

Comment: Hi Ian, ah, ok, this explains a lot.  In your case you have some `div` elements that render "like" a drop-down `select` element, however it is not actually an HTML form control. I'm also guessing that it stores the selected value in this element: `<input id="react-select-bet-param-selector-input" readonly="" tabindex="0" class="css-14uuagi" value="">`  I would look to see what API your custom dropdown element provides as that will be the only way to set your selection programmatically (and not have it break your UI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript you can set the `selectedIndex` property.

```
elem.selectedIndex = 2;
```

Setting `-1` will remove any selection, and any positive integer will select that item in the list (0-indexed)... so if you want the 3rd item, just set it to `2`.

[HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex)

The property works as a getter too, so if you want to know which element is selected, you can request it like:

```
var currentSelectedIndex = elem.selectedIndex;
```

**Full interactive example below:**

```js
var selectElem = document.getElementById('select');
var pElem = document.getElementById('p');
var buttonElem = document.getElementById('button');

selectElem.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var index = selectElem.selectedIndex;
  pElem.innerHTML = 'selectedIndex: ' + index;
});

buttonElem.addEventListener('click', function(){
  selectElem.selectedIndex = 2;
});
```

```html
<p id="p">selectedIndex: 0</p>

<select id="select">
  <option selected>Option A</option>
  <option>Option B</option>
  <option>Option C</option>
  <option>Option D</option>
  <option>Option E</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Set it to C (2)"/>
```